# How does the locale setting LC_NUMERIC work in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, locale

Could anybody give an insight on the locale and numeric types behaviour in PostgreSQL? We work with Italian locale. That is comma separation for decimal part. Setting in `postgresql.conf`

```
# These settings are initialized by initdb, but they can be changed.
lc_messages = 'it_IT.UTF-8'                     # locale for system error message
                                                # strings
lc_monetary = 'it_IT.UTF-8'                     # locale for monetary formatting
lc_numeric = 'it_IT.UTF-8'                      # locale for number formatting
lc_time = 'it_IT.UTF-8'                         # locale for time formatting
```

.. does nothing! It behaves in a quite appropriate way with dates and so, BUT the numeric type remains DOT separated for decimal part.

```
root@server:~# uname -a
Linux server 2.6.32-36-generic-pae #79-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 8 23:25:26 UTC 2011 i686 GNU/Linux

root@server:~# dpkg -l | grep postgresql
ii  postgresql-8.4      8.4.9-0ubuntu0.10.04   object-relational SQL database, version 8.4 
ii  postgresql-client   8.4.9-0ubuntu0.10.04   front-end programs for PostgreSQL (supported)
```

**EDIT**

Having problem with implementation of locale in different scopes: db, server script, os and client side. **Decided to avoid any locale formatting and use en_EN locale**. The locale formatting will be applied only at the moment of output and so.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[The manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-LC-NUMERIC):

> lc_numeric (string)
>
> Sets the locale to use for formatting numbers, for example with the to_char family of functions.

Concerns these [type formatting functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html). You should be able to reproduce the following demo:

```
SHOW lc_numeric;
```

de_AT.UTF-8

```
SELECT to_number('13,4','999D99')
```

13.4

```
SELECT to_char(13.4,'FM999D99')
```

13,4

```
SET lc_numeric = 'C';
SELECT to_number('13,4','999D99')
```

134

```
SELECT to_char(13.4,'FM999D99')
```

13.4

```
RESET lc_numeric;
```

[Template patterns in the manual.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-NUMERIC-TABLE)

The format of numbers in SQL expressions does **not** change with locale settings. That would be madness.

Aside: you have to (at least) reload the server after changing `postgresql.conf`.

```
pg_ctl reload
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yes I'm aware of to_char and other methods and server reload on config changes. But the phrase "for example with the to_char" what does "for example" means, are there any precise list WHERE it is applicable and WHERE NOT? Could it be done the automatic casting of every SELECT query to respect the locale settings even at the cost of performance?

Comment: @Igor: I *could* be done, but madness lurks down that path. It could break every piece of code that uses casts with a change of locale. So it only applies to type formatting functions that use locale-aware template patterns. You find a list of those at the link I included.

Comment: once you've step on the computer path you already took the madness path, so some more or less would not change much ;) Actually I'm searching to avoid madness, because in the case that not beeing possible to implement it the DB part I'll have to implement it in code, that is the errors for sure! Another possibility, is quite mad in you terms, is to screen the tables by views and making cast their inside (wanted to avoid even this one).