# Postgres lc_numeric not working as expected

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, locale

I'm on a project that involves a database that uses Danish numeric settings (the decimal separator is a comma). I'm trying to figure out how I can store values in the database as decimal/number/anything but text, but have them keep the comma separator. I've updated the lc_numeric setting in the AWS Parameter group to da_DK, which I found online to be the Danish locale setting, but values are still showing with the period instead of the decimal. What changes need to be made/is this possible?

For instance:

```
CREATE TABLE test ( 
    num NUMERIC 
);                             // I've also tried Decimal instead of numeric

INSERT INTO test ('1,3')       // error 
INSERT INTO test ('1.3')       // returns 1.3 when selected.
SHOW lc_numeric                // returns da_DK as expected.
SELECT * FROM test;            // 1.3
```

What am I doing wrong?

Note: this is a postgres instance via AWS RDS, any changes need to be made via the Parameter Group menu and not via the command line.

Comment: `lc_numeric` does not change how SQL accepts numbers for *input*. You can change how the *function* [`to_number`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html) uses the decimal separator and thousands separator. I don't think there is any way to change how numbers are *input* (this is normally done at the user-interface part of the application, not the DB). Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8933782/how-does-the-locale-setting-lc-numeric-work-in-postgresql?rq=1

Comment: Frankly I think that's a bug; we should respect LC_NUMERIC for input too, or not support it at all. Not being able to round-trip numeric representations is pretty dire.

Comment: @CraigRinger I don't think that's the case. `to_char` and `to_number` both respect `lc_numeric`, and the type input and output functions don't. So a "round trip" should word fine as long as you don't mix, as in `to_char(3.14, '99D99')::double precision`.

Comment: @CraigRinger and what about numeric literals? Should a parser, which respects `lc_numeric` allow this? `INSERT INTO test (1,3)` (aka. inserting a single number `1.3`). Obviously, that will never happen, but allowing `numeric '1,3'` would create an odd disparity IMHO. However, `CAST`-ing from string types is another case. It might respect `lc_numeric`.

Comment: Good points both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lc_numeric` does not influence the string input and output format of numeric types, so it also does not influence the result of type casts.

It only influences the conversion functions `to_char` and `to_number`. With regard to the decimal separator, `lc_numeric` determines the meaning of the `D` format specifier.

Comment: I don't think so - do you have an example? I am routinely using `de_DE.UTF8` and have not seen a decimal comma in `psql` yet.

Comment: I don't use psql - just thought it would (but apparently I was wrong)