# PostgreSQL on Windows 10. Locale is broken

Tags: windows, postgresql, locale

I have installed PostgreSQL version 11 on Windows 10 PC two times. First time it was from official installer for Windows, second time it was a set of packages for cygwin.

The problem is, I can't get any database locale settings to work correctly. In any of the two above cases, the Postgres cluster was initialized with `initdb` command.

With cygwin install, the command has `-E UTF8`, `--locale=uk_UA.utf8` and same for `collation` and `ctypes`. `cygwin` seemed to recognize the command, the cluster was created. Then I've created database with appropriate settings and some tables in it.

The output of simple query were plain wrong for my locale. It was `$` sign instead of `грн` for monetary, `.` insteed of `,` for fraction and so on. The official installer gave the same results, with locale set up and displayed correctly.

Same `initdb` and `create database` are giving me correct results with `linux OS`.

***initdb***

```
initdb —pgdata=... \
          —locale=uk_UA.utf8
          —lc-collate=...
          —lc-type=...
          —lc-monetary=...
          —lc-numeric=...
          —lc-time=...
          —encoding=UTF-8
```

Here, basically I’ve repeated the uk_UA.utf8 locale.
Also tried with “uk-x-icu” locale, as windows version compiled with icu library as it seems.

***The queries***

```
create database db
 template         = template0
 encoding         = 'UTF8'
 lc_collate       = 'uk_UA.utf8'
 ...              = 'uk_UA.utf8'
 lc_ctype         = 'uk_UA.utf8'
 connection_limit = -1
 is_template      = false
;

create table c_types (
 id           serial,
 c_date       date,
 c_text       text,
 c_time       time,
 c_timestamp  timestamp,
 c_money      money,
 c_float      float
);

insert into c_types(c_date,c_text,c_time,c_timestamp,c_money,c_float) values
('2019-09-01', 'text0', '00:00:01', timestamp '2019-09-01 20:00:00', 1000.0001, 1000.0001),
('2019-09-01', 'text1', '00:00:02', timestamp '2019-09-01 21:00:00', 2000.0001, 2000.0001)
;

select * from c_types;
```

***Correct output(Linux)***

```
# id |   c_date   | c_text |  c_time  |     c_timestamp     |    c_money    |  c_float  
#----+------------+--------+----------+---------------------+---------------+-----------
#  1 | 2019-09-01 | text0  | 00:00:01 | 2019-09-01 20:00:00 |  1 000,00грн. | 1000.0001
#  2 | 2019-09-01 | text1  | 00:00:02 | 2019-09-01 21:00:00 |  2 000,00грн. | 2000.0001
```

***This post shows that lc_numeric does not do influence separator in numerics as is***
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41759744/8339821

***Influenced functions are `to_number`, `to_char` etc***
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8935028/8339821

The question is, how can I set up Postgres for my locale?

Comment: Can you provide the complete `initdb` and SQL that reproduces the problem? What is your seting of `lc_monetary` when you see these results?

Comment: And the output of the `.` is controlled by `lc_numeric` if I'm not mistaken

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the quick search got me to this: http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.3.0SP3/dinkum_en/c99/locale.html#locale%20category. Look at `lconv` struct, it has `char *mon_decimal_point`. I dont think it will be much different for other systems as it must be connected to `libc` and some standards. The `float`s also have wrong fraction separator tho.

Comment: [The manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-LC-NUMERIC) is the reference you should be looking at, not some random page in the internet

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I can't be 100% sure in the exact commands. I will write full commans tommorow, from workplace. But I'am 99% sure in that that I've listed _all_ initdb parameters, and I am sure I've listed `--encoding`, `--locale`, `--lc-collate`, `--lc-ctype`... and so on. All that concerns the locale. The encoding were `UTF8`, the locale and all other locale parameters were `uk_UA.utf8`. `postgres` seemed to agree with that, have set it up(I've checked). Then I've created simple table with numbers, strings, monetary, time and so on. And the output was plain wrong.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Can't find anithing about actual formatting in that manual.  And I know that `postgres` is tight with `C` and `POSIX`.

Comment: Well, at least show some queries that produce a dollar sign or a decimal point on your system.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name maybe you meant this https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap07.html manual?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe updated to exact query. will write `initdb` from work.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name updated to exact query. will write initdb from work.

Comment: You won't get `,` for a `float8` decimal point, neither on Linux nor on Windows, unless you use the `D` format code with `to_char()`. The only thing that should be influenced is `money`. Anyway if that doesn't work as you expect on Windows: PostgreSQL gets these definitions from the operating system. Do you have that locale installed on the Windows machine?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe sure I do.

Comment: Updated to reflect initdb command.