# Replace dot by comma SQL

Tags: sql

I have the code presented below. The decimal caracter is ".". I wanna change it to ",". I was trying to use replace but it is not working.
Can you suggest me an alternative?

```
SELECT
,CASE WHEN t1."EID"='10' THEN cast(t1."PAYVal" as decimal(12,2)) ELSE cast(t1."PAYVal"*t2."EXCValue"  as decimal(12,2)) END as plata_LEI
 ,CASE WHEN t1."EID"='2' 
        THEN cast(t1."PAYVal" as decimal(12,2))
      ELSE CASE WHEN t1."EID"='10' THEN cast(t1."PAYVal"/t3."EXCValue"  as decimal(12,2))
           ELSE cast(t1."PAYVal"*t2."EXCValue"/t3."EXCValue" as decimal(12,2))
           END 
    END as plata_EUR
```

Thanks.

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are using.  I do think, however, that the issue is in the GUI you are using.  Neither commas nor periods are used to store decimal values; they use an internal format.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8935028/13808319

Comment: If this is Postgres, use `to_char()` to format the number with a locale aware decimal character.

Comment: This is a formatting issue that should be treated in the client app, not in SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use replace function because you are type casting it to decimal. You need to again type case the result to text and use replace function as below,

```
replace((CASE WHEN t1."EID"='10' THEN cast(t1."PAYVal" as decimal(12,2)) ELSE 
cast(t1."PAYVal"*t2."EXCValue"  as decimal(12,2)) END)::text, '.', ',') as plata_LEI
```